# Why does my regular expression select everything?

Tags: regex

Hey guys, I'm trying to select a specific string out of a text, but I'm not a master of regular expressions.
I tried one way, and it starts from the string I want but it matches everything after what I want too.

My regex:

```
\nSCR((?s).*)(GI|SI)(.*?)\n
```

Text I'm matching on.

```
Hierbij een test

SCR
S09
/vince@test.be
05FEB
GI BRGDS OPS

middle text string (may not selected)

SCR
S09
05FEB
LHR
NPVT700 PVT701 30MAR30MAR 1000000 005CRJ FAB1900 07301NCE DD
/ RE.GBFLY/
GI BRGDS
```

The middle string is selected, it only needs the SCR until the GI line.

Comment: Please don't refer to your Regex code as a 'he' :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match from a line starting with `SCR` to a line starting with `GI` or `SI` (inclusive), you would use the following regular expression:

```
(?m:^SCR\n(?:^(?!GI|SI).*\n)*(?:GI|SI).*)
```

This will:

- Find the start of a line.
- Match `SCR` and a new line.
- Match all lines not starting with `GI` or `SI`.
- Match the last line, requiring there to be `GI` or `SI` (this prevents it from matching to the end of the string if there is no `GI` or `SI`.

Comment: I just changed my regex a bit, inspired by Gumbo. His regular expression took into account the fact that if a group doesn't have a `GI` or `SI` line, the regular expression shouldn't match. Now my regex and his second regex are pretty similar, except that mine uses the start of line anchor `^` instead of matching a new line.

Answer (score 2):

Use the non-greedy quantifier also on the first quantifier:

```
\nSCR((?s).*?)(GI|SI)(.*?)\n
```

Or you could use a [negative look-ahead assertion `(?!`*`expr`*`)`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead) to capture just those lines that do not start with either `GI` or `SI`:

```
\nSCR((?:\n(?!GI|SI).*)*)\n(?:GI|SI).*\n
```